# Passing flash notice or alert via json to client side

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I am newbie to Rails and angularJs and i need to pass notice message with json data to my view 
this is my method create

```
def create
 @cart= Panier.create(book_id: params[:book_id], title: params[:title], price: params[:price], quantity: params[:quantity],user_id: params[:user_id])
 respond_to do |format|
  if @cart.save()

    format.json { render json: @cart, status: :created, location: @cart ,message: "added successfully to your cart" }
  else

    format.json {render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity, message: "can't be a dadded to your cart"}
  end
 end
end
```

so how can I display that messages in my web page?